# Capture SQL Results to Variable

Tags: python, sql

I want to be able to query a data base and send the results in an email:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import MySQLdb
import datetime


db = MySQLdb.connect("host","account","pass","db")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select report_date, ROUND(SUM(balance), 2) as 'Net', ROUND(SUM(short_mkt_value), 2) as 'Short', ROUND(SUM(int_balance ), 2) as 'Long' from intersum_recap where group_name = 'Carter' group by report_date order by report_date desc")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    data = (', '.join([str(u) for u in row]))

toaddr = 'email'
fromaddr = 'email'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['Subject'] = 'Net Debit by Account'

body = data
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('mail')
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, 'pass')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()

db.close()
```

After running the script, the email only contains the first line that the query should have returned. How can I capture the entire iteration of the sql query into a variable to be printed in 'msg'

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is being overwritten with every iteration. Declare `data` variable outside your `for` loop

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
data = ''
for row in rows:
    data += (', '.join([str(u) for u in row]))+'\n'
```

Comment: this is a good start, however it appends every iteration together so that its one continuous string. Any idea how I would have each iteration print on a new line?

Comment: Sure! Just add ```\n``` to the data. I have updated the answer